# JQuery click function not working after removing and adding back elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

this is my click function

```
$('.cal table tbody td').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('available'))
    {
        alert('asd');
    }
});
```

the problem i am having is that after i have switched to the next or previous month, my clicking function on the calendar does not work.

For example in my JSFIDDLE, if u move to the previous month and then move back to the current month and do the click function, it wouldn't work anymore.

EDIT: I'm using an external library called date.js, check out my jsfiddle for a clearer idea of what is going on.

EDIT 2: updated jsfiddle link

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPY68/1/)

Comment: [object Date] has no method 'isAfter'

Comment: check out my jsfiddle, im using an external library called date.js, i forgot to mention in my post.

Comment: You are using incorrect variant of `on` for dynamically created elements. Check out my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
$(document).on('click','.cal table tbody td', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('available')) {
            alert('asd');
        }
});
```

instead of this

```
$('.cal table tbody td').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('available')) {
            alert('asd');
        }
    });
```

Former is the correct replacement for `delegate`

Comment: should i be changing my other functions with `.on()` as well?

Comment: Others are static elements so there is no need but this form is preferred [see why](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

Answer (score 1):

one thing I notice immediately is that when you do things like:

```
$('#calendar tbody').append('<tr id = row'+i+'></tr>');
```

you need to remember that when you want to give an ID to an element the 'value' portion of the ID should be enclosed in quotations.

So you need to escape the string to include them so your browser can interpret the html properly.

ie

```
$('#calendar tbody').append('<tr id = \"row'+i+'\"></tr>');
```

that way your output looks like:

```
<tr id="rowx"></tr>
```

instead of:

```
<tr id=rowx></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your previous and next event handlers are recreating the DOM elements used for rendering the calendar.   However, your click handler is only only attached to the  elements that exist in the DOM at the time that handler is registered.   The documentation of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) states:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()

You'll probably need to re-register that click handler as part of your `calendarInit()` function **after** the new rows in the calendar - the new  elements - have been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You may view a working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jK9YV/5/).  Or take a look at the updated jQuery below.

```
var firstday = new Date();
var lastday = new Date();
var calendarmonth = new Date();
var CCheck;

$(document).ready(function () {
    Date.today();

    firstday.setMonth(Date.today().getMonth(), 1);
    lastday.setMonth(Date.today().getMonth() + 1, 0);
    calendarmonth.setMonth(Date.today().getMonth());

    calendarInit();

    $('#calendar-prev').on('click', function () {
        if (CCheck > 35) {
            //render 6 rows
            for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                $('#row' + i).remove();
            }
        } else {
            //render 5 rows
            for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                $('#row' + i).remove();
            }
        }
        $("#month").empty();
        calendarmonth.addMonths(-1);
        firstday.addMonths(-1);
        lastday.setMonth(firstday.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        calendarInit();
    });

    $('#calendar-next').on('click', function () {
        if (CCheck > 35) {
            //render 6 rows
            for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                $('#row' + i).remove();
            }
        } else {
            //render 5 rows
            for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                $('#row' + i).remove();
            }
        }
        $("#month").empty();
        calendarmonth.addMonths(1);
        firstday.addMonths(1);
        lastday.setMonth(firstday.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        calendarInit();
    });
    addRemoveClickTrigger();

});

function calendarInit() {
    CCheck = lastday.getDate() + firstday.getDay();
    var i;
    var colNo;
    var a = 1;
    var days = new Array();
    $("#month").append("Month: " + calendarmonth.toString("MMMM, yyyy"));
    if (CCheck > 35) {
        //render 6 rows
        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            $('#calendar tbody').append('<tr id = row' + i + '></tr>');
            colNo = a + 6;
            for (a; a <= colNo; a++) {
                var datenum = a - firstday.getDay();
                if (datenum < 1) {
                    $('#row' + i).append('<td></td>');
                } else if (datenum > lastday.getDate()) {
                    $('#row' + i).append('<td></td>');
                } else {
                    $('#row' + i).append('<td id = Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + datenum + '>' + datenum + '</td>');
                    days[datenum] = new Date();
                    days[datenum].set({
                        month: calendarmonth.getMonth(),
                        day: datenum,
                        year: calendarmonth.getFullYear()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        //render 5 rows
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            $('#calendar tbody').append('<tr id = row' + i + '></tr>');
            colNo = a + 6;
            for (a; a <= colNo; a++) {
                var datenum = a - firstday.getDay();
                if (datenum < 1) {
                    $('#row' + i).append('<td></td>');
                } else if (datenum > lastday.getDate()) {
                    $('#row' + i).append('<td></td>');
                } else {
                    $('#row' + i).append('<td id = Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + datenum + '>' + datenum + '</td>');
                    days[datenum] = new Date();
                    days[datenum].set({
                        month: calendarmonth.getMonth(),
                        day: datenum,
                        year: calendarmonth.getFullYear()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*alert(Date.today().getMonth());
    alert(calendarmonth.getMonth());*/
    if (Date.today().getMonth() == calendarmonth.getMonth() && Date.today().getFullYear() == calendarmonth.getFullYear()) {
        for (i = 1; i <= lastday.getDate(); i++) //Date highlight
        {
            if (Date.today().getDate() == i) //highlight today's date
            {
                $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).addClass("today");
            } else if (Date.today().getDate() > i) //highlight unavailable dates
            {
                $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).addClass("unavailable");
            } else if (Date.today().getDate() < i) {
                $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).addClass("available");
            }
        }
    } else if (Date.today() > calendarmonth) {
        for (i = 1; i <= lastday.getDate(); i++) //Highlight dates before today to unavailable
        {
            $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).addClass("unavailable");
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i <= lastday.getDate(); i++) //Condition highlighting
        {
            $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).addClass("available");
            if (days[i].getDay() == 0 || days[i].getDay() == 6) // set weekends to unavailable
            {
                $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).removeClass("available");
                $('#Y' + calendarmonth.getFullYear() + 'M' + calendarmonth.getMonth() + 'Day' + i).addClass("unavailable");
            }
        }
    }
    addRemoveClickTrigger();
} //calendarInit()

function addRemoveClickTrigger()
{
    $('.cal table tbody td').off();
    $('.cal table tbody td').on({
        'click':
        function () 
        {
            alert(jQuery(this).prop('class'));
            if ($(this).hasClass('available')) 
            {
                alert('asd');
            }
        }
    });        
} //addRemoveClickTrigger()
```

I hope this helps.