# Rails 4 + Jquery redirect pages using jquery then back, the jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an issue with this code on ruby using jquery, I am redirecting using Jquery, then going back using a back button. And it only works the first time, if you go back from the redirect it just not bind to the DOM.

Code:

```
$(function(){
    $('tr.item').bind("click", function(){
            window.location.href = "/products/" + $(this).attr('id');
        // Or, we can grab the HREF from the first anchor:
        // window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

PS: I already tried the window.onunload trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution base on:[JQuery click function not working after removing and adding back elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962402/jquery-click-function-not-working-after-removing-and-adding-back-elements)

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", 'tr.item', function(){
            window.location.href = "/products/" + $(this).attr('id');
        // Or, we can grab the HREF from the first anchor:
        // window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

I Don't understand why this works on after after go back from the link execute, but it seems that the document need to be the root object.